# Enabling Windows Authentication Option not available in Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, iis, windows-authentication

I have started IIS 10 on my system and its showing error 401.3. Found resolution to enable Windows Authentication in Windows 10 Features but its not present there.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is present on Windows 10 Pro. This feature is not present on your system because you're using Windows 10 Home.

[image: Windows Features]

Comment: Is there any package or any other way to add this feature in my Home version?

Comment: No, there isn't.